# Two SUM() Queries on the Same Table But Using Different Where Clauses

Tags: php, mysql

I'm guessing there's a simple solution there somewhere, but it's driving me mad trying to get it to work. I want to perform two `SUM()` queries on the same table but they both have different `WHERE` clauses.

The table is used for a user voting system, so users vote on other users content. I want to be able to list the current user's activity (content/categories they've added), and combine it with details of how many other users have voted for the current users content.

Essentially i want to combine the two queries below from the same table.

```
SELECT category_id,
SUM(content_add) AS content_add_count,
SUM(category_add) AS category_add_count
FROM table1 WHERE user_id = '" . $user_id . "' GROUP BY category_id


SELECT SUM(normal_vote) AS agree_votes
FROM table1
WHERE issued_by_user != '" . $user_id . "'
AND user_id = '" . $user_id . "'
AND plus = '1'
GROUP BY category_id
```

I've tried putting the second query within another `SUM()` in the first query above but that obviously can't be done in MySQL, but that's what I'd like to achieve if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  category_id
  ,SUM(content_add) AS content_add_count
  ,SUM(category_add) AS category_add_count
  ,SUM(if(issued_by_user != '" . $user_id . "' AND plus = '1',normal_vote,0)) AS agree_votes
FROM table1 
WHERE user_id = '" . $user_id . "' 
GROUP BY category_id
```

Comment: I was about to write this answer, after seeing the first three.

Comment: +1 This is the way I would recommend. The "trick" here is to include a value in the SUM based on conditional tests, moving those conditional tests from the WHERE clause into the expression in the SELECT list.  A CASE expression would be the more generic approach to the MySQL-specific IF() function.

Comment: I put if as if is the preferred mysql function. And in a more casual way is easier to understand than a case. If mysql was not the tag used I would have used a case which is generic.